# webpack - how to create split bundle with a single entrypoint

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, javascript-build

How to benefit from code splitting of webpack, while merging all of it into a single entry point?
Say my entry points are following:

```
entry: {
    polyfills: '@babel/polyfill',
    react: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    app: resolve(appDir, 'index.js'),
},

// plus additional relevant config blocks:
...
output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].chunk.js',
},
...
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
    },
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
},
```

This would create multiple entrypoints that all need to be loaded into the page (like babel polyfills, runtime, vendors chunk...) before the main app itself.

How could webpack be instructed so that only a single `script` tag needs to be injected into the page, which then lazily pulls all the chunks it needs?

This would ease injecting libraries into an app during runtime - easier to send only single script location from the backend, instead of multiple (and making sure correct order is preserved).

Comment: Can you show your whole webpack config ? Especially the "output" key.

Comment: Added relevant bits of webpack.conf.

Comment: For split code that's not an entry point, you would use `require.ensure`  https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure   But do be aware this is not a standard, so if you made a library, and then stopped using webpack you have some code updating to do.  But I believe webpack now support the dynamic import, which is more standard.

Comment: But that requires manual tracking of dependencies, correct?
What about the `vendors` chunk that gets created by splinChunks?

Answer (score 0):

Guess my initial understanding of webpack workings was flawed.

Defining `splitChunks.chunks: 'all'` & separate runtime and having a truly *single* entrypoint (ie `script` tag to include) are mutually exclusive.